# Ajax setting variable not working in different scopes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, scope

I'm trying to set a js var using a ajax call. Then the var value is inputed into a form element.
It works fine until the point I try to use the var the way shown below.

the function I use to fetch the val

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
  var val;
  $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
    val=data;
  });
  return val;
}
```

I'll skip crud.php code, since it's working for another scripts and it only queries MySQL, and echoes the value.

Then I call ajaxFetch function triggered by a click

```
$(document).on("click",".btnCall",function(){
  id=$(this).data("id")//gets an id from a data tag
  q1 = "SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE ID="+id;
  userName = ajaxFetch(q1);
  $("#form_userName").val(userName);
});
```

What I can't understand, but I guess it's a scope issue, is the following

1. If I do things the way is shown, the form remains empty
2. If I do a direct ajax call, within the click trigger (not calling the
   function), the form is filled with the user's name.
3. If I do things the way shown above, but I add an "alert(val)" into the ajaxFetch function (I use this to test the function), the alert will be
   "undefined" but the form WILL be filled with the value.

I ran into the issue this way: I first made the ajax call within the "click" event. Then I created the ajaxFetch function, as there will be a couple of calls. I added an "alert" to both function and "click" event, so I could see if the fetch was working properly. 
The first thing I've noticed was that the first alert (inside ajaxFetch) was empty, but the alert inside the click event was showing the value.

Thanks in advance. sorry for any mistakes

**EDIT - the way worked (using unwanted alerts)**

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
  var val;
  $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
    val=data;

    alert(data);

  });
  return val;
}

$(document).on("click",".btnCall",function(){
  id=$(this).data("id")//gets an id from a data tag
  q1 = "SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE ID="+id;
  userName = ajaxFetch(q1);

  alert(userName)

  $("#form_userName").val(userName);
});
```

this way the form value *will* be filed. The first alert will show an *empty string* and the second alert will show the right value.

**FINAL EDIT - working Ajax request**

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
  var r;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/ajax/crud.php',
    async:false,
    data:{mode:"fetch",query:query},
     success: function(response){
       r=response;
     }
  });
  return r;
}
```

This way (adding the option "async:false")var will be only filled when ajax finishes it's request. Not really a pro tip, but may help another beginners.

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to set a var when ajax hasn't finished the request. Using the option "async:false" within my ajax request solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Return the `val` inside a `$.post` function liked this.

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
  var val;
  $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
    val=data;
    //return statement should be here and not out side the ajax function
    return val;
  });
}
```

}

Comment: It makes sense, thanks, but didn't solve my problem... I still get undefined val... 
I edited the question, so maybe it gives more clues about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you use `val` which is `undefined` at the moment when you return it.
You should perform all logic which uses `val` in callback function, in other case you just cannot know when request is completed. I suggest you to use it like:

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
  return $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query});
}
//and where you call ajaxFetch()
ajaxFetch().then(function(data) {
  val=data;
  //do something with val here
});
```

Comment: thanks, pal,  I think this is the way to go. 
What I can't understand is why it works if I use an "alert" function... 

Could you explain it to me? 
Furthermore, if I put an alert(val) inside ajaxFetch function, and another where it's called (inside the "click" event), the first alert will be empty and the second will be filled with the value..

Comment: sorry answering before testing... The solution you provided returns an object, not a value.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing Async Ajax call. So you will have to modify your code a bit as follows:

```
function ajaxFetch(query) {
    var val;
    $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
            val=data;

            $("#form_userName").val(val); //set the value right in success handler of Ajax
     });

  }

    $(document).on("click",".btnCall",function(){
      id=$(this).data("id")//gets an id from a data tag
      q1 = "SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE ID="+id;
      ajaxFetch(q1); //just call the function; you don't know how much time Ajax will take to get back the result.

    });
```

Comment: thanks for your input. What I didn't mention on the question is that this routine will be used to return about 6 fields, that's why I was trying to create a function which should be fed with the proper query, to return the field I need

Anyway I think that one solution it's to pass the element's ID to the function, along with the query, so I can call the same function for all the fields. 

Something like this
`function ajaxFetch(query,id){
    $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
       $(id).val(data); 
     });
 }`

Comment: the only problem is that some of the value have to be treated: some date values has to be localized, as some currency values. 
So maybe I'll have to pass another argument, to the function and perform a switch, to do the proper conversion, for the type of value received...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
var val,id,q1,userName;
function returnData(param)
{
   $("#form_userName").val(param);
}
function ajaxFetch(query, callback)
{
  var x = $.post( "/ajax/crud.php",{mode:"fetch",query:query},function(data) {
    callback(data);
  })
}
$(document).on("click",".btnCall",
    function(){
        id=$(this).data("id")//gets an id from a data tag
        q1 = "SELECT NAME FROM user WHERE ID="+id;
        ajaxFetch(q1,returnData);
    }
);
```

since it is an asynchronous, use callback function

Comment: I think for me 2 functions will work best, because at 1 click at ".btnCall" I actually need it to fill aprox. 6 fields. (name, date of birth, address...)
it's used to update the person records. 
But I understand the way you did would work fine for the example I gave.
thank you

Comment: I think one workaround to that would be creating a function which would receive 3 parameters: the query, a mode parameter, which would tell any treatment the value could need (localization of monetary values and dates) and id to the element which would receive the treated value.
Anyway I tried an approach like this and the result was the same: the val returns "undefined" even though I know it was defined (using "alerts" to test). 
As I mentioned before, if I use one alert on the function itself and another on the event, the val will be defined, but on the second alert. 
Still a mistery to me.

Comment: Thanks Basil for your effort trying to help. I figured out what was happening: it was an sync issue. 
I was trying to set a value to a var at a time that Ajax hasn't finished the request. 
I solved the problem by including a "async:false" option within my Ajax request. 
I'm really a newbie on ajax, so I couldn't figure it out early. So when I was using 2, or 3 alerts to show the var's value, the request had time to finish. 
Anyway, thanks again.